# Write a query that remove duplicate that have a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is not the question but it's similar.

First i solved the query by I using unary join and calculated what required (distance) now I want to count how many pairs have the shortest distance without duplication. Example

```
ID   ID   Distance
1    2    0.1
2    1    0.1
3    5    0.13
4    7    0.1
```

The answer should be 2 but I get 3 as I don’t know how to remove the duplication between 2,1 and 1,2.

Would anyone please help me the answer should be (number of pairs , shortest distance )

Comment: show your query that gets 3

Comment: Show your original query *(the one that generate those four rows of sample data)*.  It may be that you can reformulate that query to avoid the duplication *(possibly simply be enforcing that id1 must be less than id2)*

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, you can use `count(distinct)` but with a twist:

```
select distance, count(distinct least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2))
from t
group by distance
order by distance
limit 1;
```

Comment: How can I do it using where condition rather than least greatest ?

Comment: @user870251 . . . You could use `case` instead, but I see no reason for that.  This answers the question that you asked.